# Regular Expression to remove the first section from src attribute of an image

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regular expression able to replace the first section from src property of an image.

The image html looks like this

```
var example="<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/....."
```

I need to replace all characters before the first comma (,) and replace it for an empty string, the "jpeg" section should be generic.

I tried that one but didn't work:

```
string res = example.Replace(@"/^data:image\/\w +\;base64,", "");
```

Comment: remove first ^ and try again?

Comment: didn't work. :(

Comment: there is a space between `\w` and `+` , remove it

Comment: you wrongly use the function, it shoud be Regular.Replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var example="<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/.....";
        string res = Regex.Replace(example, "data:image\\/\\w+\\;base64\\,", "");
        Console.WriteLine(res);
    }
}
```

and the output is

```
<img src="/9j/.....
```

Comment: ups, yes...Thanks @Kris, Mi mind is a mix between JavaScript and c# now.